# helm dask multiple nodes

Tags: dask, kubernetes-helm

I have a kubernetes cluster composed of two machines. I want one machine to be the `scheduler` and both to be the `workers.`
I installed the `helm dask` as follows per the official instructions: 
`helm install --name my-release dask/dask`
However, I noticed on the `kubernetes dashboard` that schedule and workers are only installed on one node instead of both. How do I create workers on both nodes with the helm dask?
Even when I choose the `dask-cuda-worker`option, it doesn't select the computer with the nvidia GPU. 
Someone please help me get workers on both nodes?

Answer (score 0):

You probably can do this with a [node-selector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#step-two-add-a-nodeselector-field-to-your-pod-configuration).  For your case maybe you want something like:

### Label nodes:

> kubectl label nodes  accelerator=nvidia-tesla-p100
>
> helm install --name my-release dask/dask --set nodeSelector.accelerator=nvidia-tesla-p100